# Storing emoji's in MySQL getting incorrect String value error

Tags: java, mysql, json

I am storing data which contains emoji's the data is coming in the json form so when I retrieve it comes like

> **"Giggs'ern har vært å koset seg igjen(square bracket) Dette er en fillesak"**

when I store it into MySQL I got this error:

> 2016-05-0213:12:45.582 [ERROR] pool-1-thread-1 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Incorrect string
>   value: `'\xF0\x9F\x98\x8A\x0A<...'` for column `'comment'` at row 1

I have changed the 
MySQL database encoding to `utf8mb4` but it did not solve the problem.

Comment: A few questions: is the column a varchar or a blob? are you trying to store a binary or a base64 representation of the emoji? Can you provide the piece of code when you call Hibernate? and maybe a data sample?

Comment: You also need to tell the MySQL driver to use Unicode unfortunately. In the connection string, google it. A box could also be a font without that emoji character.

Comment: yes the column is text type and storing string data only , i m using simple jdbc insert @sanF

Comment: Did you change the collate of the column as well? I saw other similar posts where they solved it changing the collate to `utf8mb4_general_ci`. Maybe that works.

Comment: yes i have changed the collate of table and the columns as well still i am getting logs like this 
11:48:44,027 ERROR SqlExceptionHelper:146 - Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x91\x8D\xF0\x9F...' for column 'comment' 
and getting [?][?][?] instead of emojis 
@SanF

Comment: i have changed hibernate now instead of JDBC and  did changes in configuration 
setProperty("hibernate.connection.CharSet","utf8mb4");
    setProperty("hibernate.connection.characterEncoding","utf8");
    setProperty("hibernate.connection.useUnicode","true");

none of the solution is working...

Answer (score 8):

Please, follow these steps.

1. Database: Change Database default collation as utf8mb4.
2. Table: Change table collation as CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin.

How to alter Table

```
ALTER TABLE Table CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin
```

SQLCopy

3. Set utf8mb4 in database connection:

```
  $database_connection = new mysqli($server, $user, $password, $database);
 
  $database_connection->set_charset('utf8mb4');
```

Answer (score 3):

THIS WORK FOR ME!

Change your character set of your table to `utf8mb4` and collation to `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`. Lastly, change data type of your column you want to store emoji to `blob` or `longblob`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to use `utf8mb4` encoding instead of `utf8` (synonym for `utf8mb3`) both as the storage encoding (server side) and all the connections' encoding (clients' side).

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing a similar issue in java and don't have the flexibility to change the charset and collate encoding of the database or that's not working for you, then this answer is for you.

you can use the [Emoji Java](https://github.com/vdurmont/emoji-java) library to achieve the same. You can convert into alias before saving/updating into database and convert back to unicode post save/update/load from database. The main benefit is readability of the text even after the encoding because this library only alias the emoji's rather than whole string.